# Altering (adding) field value when is unknown

Tags: nodes

I have three content types (A,B,C). A and B have *title*, *author*, and *field_version* (a custom field), while C doesn't have *field_version*. Let's assume I have a method that gets the version value from a node. (The `$node` parameter is an entity object.)

```
function getLatestVersion($node) {
   $version = $node->get('field_version'); //for A, B is OK, but for C - field_version is unknown
}
```

How can I check the field exists for the node passed as argument without comparing the node type with an hard-coded list?

Comment: `if (!empty($node->get('field_version'))) { $version = $no...`

Answer (score 2):

For nodes, like for every content entity, you can use code similar to the  following one to check if a Field API field(<sup>*</sup>) exists.

```
if ($node->hasField('field_version')) {
  // The node has that field; access it with $node->hasField('field_version').
}
```

A more generic code that would work for either Field API fields or non-field properties would be similar to the following one.

```
if (isset($node->field_version)) {
  // The node has that field/property; access it with $node->field_version.
}
```

<sup>*</sup> I am using the terminology used in a comment for code in [`ContentEntityBase::__isset()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3A__isset/9.0.x).

```
// "Official" Field API fields are always set. For non-field properties,
// check the internal values.
return $this->hasField($name) ? TRUE : isset($this->values[$name]);
```